# sql count of multiple tables possible inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table called Jobs and 02 other tables (places and times) that connect to Jobs by the JobID.
So, based on the tables below, I need the following in SQL server:

```
Jobs (JobID,Company)

123     ABC

456     DEF

789     GHI


PLACES (Country,JobID)
BR          123
EU          123
CA          456
```

TIMES(time,JobID)

```
05          456

08          123

09          789
```

Needed query Result:

```
QRYRESULT(JobID,CountOFPLaces,CountofTimes)

123 ,       2,                      1

456 ,       1 ,                 1

789 ,           ,               1
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so show what you've tried! Joining the three tables together using ANSII standard joins and grouping by job ID and doing a `JobId, count (Distinct Country), count(DISTINCT time)` in the select should give you the desired results.  be sure to `group by JobID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There keys here are knowing that using an outer join can give you all results for all jobs and that a count(distinct field)  will give you distinct counts eliminating the additional counts added by joins (assuming each record is unique  and that duplicates don't exist in a given table)

```
SELECT J.jobID, 
    count(Distinct P.Country) as CountOfPlaces, 
    Count(Distinct T.Time) as CountOfTimes
FROM Jobs J
LEFT JOIN Places P
 on J.JobID=P.JobID
LEFT JOIN Times T
 on T.JobID = J.JobID
GROUP BY J.JobID
```

Comment: Perfect! I guess I had the "inner" join stuck on my mind on my approach. DISTINCT in here made the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, pc, pt
from jobs j
left join (select jobid, count(Country) pc from Places group by JobId) p
on j.id = p.JobId
left join (select jobid, count([time]) pt from Times group by JobId) t
on j.id = t.JobId
```

You should use "group by" statement to count rows with the same job id for the tables "Places" and "Times" and then join it to "Jobs" table.
 I also wanted to focus that you should use subquery in join statement, otherwise you get wrong data.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked too, but I tried with the DISTINCT approach . SO far so good .

Comment: These two queries work. But if you look at the execution plan for query with distinct, you find that the plan contains 'Sort' operator. For big count of rows this operation will be expensive.